# Search result displays unparsed HTML in tag excerpt

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, user-interface, search

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/search?q=test+[bash]

> [image: the tag contains some HTML, you see]

The URL above leads to the result you see in the picture.  Note the unprocessed HTML `<span class='search-highlight'>BASH </span>`.  Removing the first term from search also removes the error. This paragraph was included to meet quality standards.

Comment: [Already logged on SE meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322139/341145)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a network-wide problem instead of a local one. The solution should be sought at the main Meta. This question is a cross-site duplicate of [Unparsed HTML shows on search result page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/322139/269301).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed by removing these highlights from tag excerpts altogether. Details: [Unparsed HTML shows on search result page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/322139/unparsed-html-shows-on-search-result-page/323262#323262)